# My Website does'nt work properly after uploading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My website works properly in my pc without no error. I tested it on ubuntu and also on windows. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ0mF.jpg) when I open it in my pc, but after uploading it to my host service it doesn't look properly [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLHyc.jpg)

I added all images, bootstrap, jquery and css to folder called source.

I don't have any idea about where the problem is.Here is my links.the problem can be href but I am not sure.

### UPDATE

I tried all your solutions (Adding / other answers and commends) I found the problem after inspecting element here it is [image]

### UPDATE 2

I solved second problem by changing permissions of all folders which is in my host company

```
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Sources/Pictures/logo4.png" type="image/ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/Slider/demo/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/Slider/dist/slippry.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sources/Style.css">
```

Comment: All your URLs there are relative, you should probably prefix them with a `/`

Comment: It looks like path problems.

Comment: U can also try use this: `<head> <base href="http://site.cm/"> ... </head>`, where `http://site.cm/` is your site's URL.

Comment: @Cactus Use absolute URLs in local resource paths? I don't think so

Comment: you said that your folder called "source" but in href your folder called "Sources"

Comment: @JeremyThille, i said about his remote host..

Comment: Please check my updated answer, and give us something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I think it is less likely that you have a path problem, as images are displayed correctly but none of the CSS is "kicking in".
Secondly, using a mix of upper and lower can cause problems (better to use all lowercase) particularly when developing on a Windows machine (doesn't distinguish between upr and lwr) and Linux (case sensitive) but I can see you are working on Ubuntu, so this is unlikely the cause.

What I have seen in the past is that an error ignored on your machine may prevent the page loading when uploaded- to check this, use the [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) here.

Next, it is possible that files are not transferring correctly to the server when you use your FTP client- log into the server File manager and have a look.

Next, look at the uploaded page in your browser, and use Ctrl+F5 in case your browser is serving a cached version from before the page was fully uploaded.

If this is ok, then see if you can view the source code in the browser for each of the CSS files- tedious I know, but may help to identify a prob.

I agree with the earlier poster that a rep of the file structure would also be useful to help debug- please let us know how you get on.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much I used validator and I viewed the source code so  I updated the post you can take a look

Comment: Glad that worked FerhatA- if you tick this as the right answer it would be much appreciated by a noob trying to earn some rep :)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you said that your folder called "source" but in href your folder called "Sources" 
try like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Sources/Pictures/logo4.png" type="image/ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/Slider/demo/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/Slider/dist/slippry.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Sources/Style.css">
```

or like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/source/Pictures/logo4.png" type="image/ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/Slider/demo/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/Slider/dist/slippry.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/source/Style.css">
```

Depends on how correctly the folder is called

Comment: Thank You. I wrote it to post wrong sorry ıt must be Sources .adding / didn't helped because The problem is different I updated the post so you can take a look

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right paths. Href atribute is 100% case-sensitive. So double check your paths again. 
Then you can use chrome dev tools or firebug to check for the paths its trying to take to the files.

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../source/Pictures/logo4.png" type="image/ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/Slider/demo/demo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/Slider/dist/slippry.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../source/Style.css">
```

Please try this :)
-- Update --

Please post Project tree so we know where are the parts you need, to do so:

1) Open CMD

2) Navigate to your projects folder by typing : `cd C:\my\path\to\XAMPPorOther\htdocs\`

3) Then run command in CMD : `tree /f > tree.txt`

4) Now you will have all folder and file structure so we can examine in your projects folder under file "tree.txt" please update your question with that information.

Comment: one of my usual mistakes when homebrewing :D